# Xtext Multiple DSL cross referencing: How to retrieve correct proxy-resolved resourceset

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dsl, xtext

I running into a problem in Xtext 2.7.2 configuring 2 DSL language working together:

I have 2 DSL with file extension named: .model and .type respectively, a project can contain 2 types of files under src/model/ folder.

example of .type file

```
entity ent2{
  name="avv"
}
```

example of .model file

```
block{
  using ent2
}
```

just a simple example on how the linkage works. The current situation now is that in the IGenerator class for the block dsl returns the fully resolved resource with the value of type dsl:

```
class BlockGenerator implements IGenerator {

    override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess fsa) {

        (Block)resource.getContents().get(0); //correct with entity type 
    }

}
```

However in Model.UI project, we tried to implement a function to get the resourceset from an IProject user has selected in the workspace, assuming that the IProject will be passed to this class below:

```
@Inject
IResourceSetProvider resourceSetProvider;

protected BlockModel loadModelResource(IProject project) {
    ResourceSet rs = resourceSetProvider.get(project);

    File srcModelDirectory = new File(project.getLocation().toFile()
            .getAbsolutePath()
            + "/src/models/");

    File[] files = srcModelDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".model");
        }
    });

    File a = files[0];

    Resource resource = rs.getResource(URI.createURI(a.toString()), true);

    EcoreUtil.resolveAll(resource);

    return (BlockModel) resource.getContents().get(0);
}
```

However this time , the ent2's name is null if we follow the same example as I mention on top. The injector is retrieved as usual UI project generated by :

```
  public class BlockExecutableExtensionFactory extends  AbstractGuiceAwareExecutableExtensionFactory {

      @Override
      protected Bundle getBundle() {
        returnBlockActivator.getInstance().getBundle();
      }

      @Override
      protected Injector getInjector() {
        return BlockActivator.getInstance().getInjector(BlockActivator.ORG_BLOCK);
}
```

}

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem? I could not figure what is the problem behind the xtext returning null for all the values of 'entity' ent2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Eclipse resource API rather than java.io.File. Something like this should do the trick to find all files.

```
IFolder folder = IProject.getFolder("src/model");
IResource[] members = folder.members();
for(IResource member: members) {
  if (member instanceof IFile && member.getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("model") {
    file = (IFile)member;
    break;
  }
}
```

Please take a look at [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/EMF/FAQ#How_do_I_map_between_an_EMF_Resource_and_an_Eclipse_IFile.3F) FAQ entry on how to obtain a proper platform:/resource URI for an Eclipse IFile

Comment: Do you mean that the problem I have is due to the fact that I am using Java IO file instead of IFile ?